# Use simple & useful ruby methods such as basename in RubyMotion

Tags: ruby, cocoa, rubymotion, macruby

RubyMotion does not support

```
require
```

in code (only in RakeFile).

Is there a way to use useful classes built into Ruby but not  into RubyMotion ? For instance, I'd like to be able to do a

```
name=Pathname.new("/path/to/some/file").basename
```

rather than look for Cocoa equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pathname` is one of those pieces of the [Ruby Standard Library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/) that are not available in RubyMotion.

You can try with [MotionBundler](http://blog.rubymotion.com/post/50983350225/motionbundler-good-old-fashioned-requirements-for), but I personally haven't been very lucky with that.

I'd suggest to use the Cocoa equivalent.
Something like:

```
name = "/path/to/some/file".lastPathComponent
```

Not that bad, anyway.